# Custom WCF AlgorithmSuite in Config File

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have created a custom algorithm suite class following the instruction on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg617968(v=vs.110).aspx. However, instead of specifying the class in code, I want to specify the custom class in the XML configuration file. Is it possible?

Example:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1">
        <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="MyCustomAlgorithmSuite"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  You may need to use a custom binding.

Comment: It appears that [Creating User-Defined Bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733893(v=vs.110).aspx) is the only way...